# How to draw funnel plots in Python?

Tags: python, data-visualization, plotly

I have seen this for R:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5195/how-to-draw-funnel-plot-using-ggplot2-in-r

Is there a way of doing this in Python? Unfortunately due to the name, every tutorial I find is for the other funnel plot which isnt what I want.

I.e. I am looking to do this in Python:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: The [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) has almost every example you can imagine.

Comment: Thank you. I had already been through that gallery and could not see any funnel plots :/

Comment: Have you found anything?

Comment: Hey, if you check my post history you'll find the answer in two of the posts. I ended up using R through rpy2 in python. I would look for you but I'm at work